# Why doesn't my Python function convert the column to datetime format

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write a function to convert a column to datetime format (has to be in a function). When i run below however, it doesnt seem to do anything. Any ideas where i am going wrong?

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'DOB': {1: '01/04/1973', 2: '01/03/1979', 3: '22/06/2005', 4: '01/03/1994'}})

def update_col(df_name):
    pd.to_datetime(df_name['DOB'])

update_col(data)
data
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't save the change to the dataframe:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'DOB': {1: '01/04/1973', 2: '01/03/1979', 3: '22/06/2005', 4: '01/03/1994'}})

def update_col(df_name):
    df_name['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df_name['DOB'])

update_col(data)
data
```

Comment: Also you might need the `dayfirst=True` parameter to to_datetime().  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: I am an idiot! completely missed that (still learning). Thanks for sharing.

Comment: No worries, that still happens after years ;)